# Progress 4gl printer not following inputted number of copies

Tags: progress-4gl

We are using a new printer unit but it didn't follow the inputted number of copies. We tried to print it on our old printer and it was able to follow the number of copies. The number of copies worked in DocuCentre S2320 printer but not in HP LaserJet Pro P1102.

This is the code used for calling the report.The numCopy variable is used for the number of copies.
`RUN _printrb(rptDir,"Summary Report","","O","","","D","?","","",numCopy,vPage[1],vPage[2],no,"",yes,yes,no,"").`

Comment: What is _printrb? I'm not familiar with it. What is the old printer, what is the new printer. I'm presuming the new printer accepts different control codes to the old one. You'll have to look at what _printrb is doing in numCopy and google the syntax of the control code for the new printer.

Comment: Perhaps different settings in the old vs the new printer? @jdpjamesp It's actually a part of the old report builder.

Comment: Oh yes of course - it's been such a long time since I used it. Probably because it was deprecated such a long time ago!!